# rename a vector in reverse in r

Tags: r, vector

I would like to rename the rest of the variables that do not match my vector, but I do not know what the appropriate code would be, I add an example.

```
example<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
keep<-c("b","c","d")
example[example %in% -keep] <- "vocal"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate (`!`) instead of `-` to reverse the logical output i.e. `TRUE -> FALSE` and viceversa

```
example[!example %in% keep] <- "vocal"
```

---

If we want to use `-`, wrap with `which` to get the position index and then use

```
example[-which(example %in% keep)] <- "vocal"
```

but this is buggy and can have unexpected output in certain cases.  e.g. if there are no matches

```
> keep1 <- c("f", "l")
> which(example %in% keep1)
integer(0)
> -which(example %in% keep1)
integer(0)
> example[-which(example %in% keep1)] <- "vocal"
> example
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Here, none of them is changed because the `which` returned no elements, which had no impact with `-`